# How to wire up data context in modular application?

Tags: mvvm, datacontext

I am writing an application, WPF, using PRISM. I'm new so apologies if this question is poor form:

I have a module that up to now has a user control for displaying a list of inspections. My module has entities written and a DbContext class to access DB. My question is where should this get initialsed and passed into my ViewModel???????

Shell XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ChargeMgm.Desktop.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
        Title="EMS" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontFamily="Calibri"
                   FontSize="16"
                   Foreground="SteelBlue"
                   Margin="5">Street Works Modules</TextBlock>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" CornerRadius="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
        <ItemsControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>


</Window>
```

Bootstrapper class

```
   class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return new Shell();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();

            App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
            App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        {
            base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
            ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
            moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(DefectModule.DefectModule));
        }
    }
```

Module

```
public class DefectModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;
    private IUnityContainer container;

    public DefectModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        container.RegisterType<IDefectsView, DefectsView>();
        container.RegisterType<IDefectsViewModel, DefectsViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<IDefectContext, DefectContext>();
        var view = container.Resolve<IDefectsView>();
        if(regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("MainRegion"))
        {
            regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Add(view);
            //regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(IDefectsView));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by initialised?  If you're using Prism what dependency container are you using (Unity or MEF)?

Comment: Which is best option? I'm proper new to this modular stuff. Just wondering how best to get my datacontext setup and in my VM and also how to get my VM hooked into my view???????????????

Comment: Have used Unity so have a bootstrapper class in my application, do you know how I register my modules' data context and view model so when my module loads I can populate a list of objects on screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Unity then you're in luck.  If you need it initialise you DB context then you can do something like this:

IModule implementation code (for your module)

```
   // Create Module http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648781.aspx
    public class Module:IModule
    {
    private IUnityContainer _container;
    public Module(IUnityContainer container,IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
    _regionManager=regionManager;
    _container=container;
    }
    public Initialize()
    {
        _container.RegisterType<IView,View>();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewModel,ViewModel>();
        _container.RegisterType<IDBContext,DbContext>();
        var view=_container.Resolve<IView>();
        //Create Region http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648829.aspx
        _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Add(view);
    }
    }
```

The above will register all of your view, viewmodel and dbcontext, resolve them and add them into a region.  For the above to work I'm expecting the following:

```
public class View:IView
{
    public View(IViewModel viewModel)
    {
    }
}

public class ViewModel:IViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(IDbContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm expecting your viewmodel to be injected into your View and your DB Context to be injected into your ViewModel using [Constructor Injection](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/79/posts/11527/dependency-injection-with-microsoft-unity-application-block.aspx).

BTW - the links in the code go to MS sites that will provide more background on Module creation and Regions.  I've got one final link:  This is a "Hello World" Prism app.  It's for Silverlight but this is basically the same thing as a WPF app in terms of code structure so should be useful:[Prism Hello World](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229931/Understand-MVVM-Using-PRISM-by-Hello-World-Silverl)

Comment: Cheers for the help chief. I have my app compiling and stepping through I can see Unity instantiating my VMs and Views and dataContext but when I add my view to the region nothing appears. Do you know of any daft step I might have missed out?

Comment: What control are you using for your Region?  Could you edit your question, above, to include your Xaml for the Region?

Comment: Appreciate your help with this chief. Be good for me to get my mind into this prism/unity concetp as seems to be everywhere......

Comment: What a bum... In my overloaded constructor I had omitted to call InitializeComponent!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! What a tool. Thanks for your assistance mate. Really helped a lot. Cheers.

Comment: You've helped loads mate. Very much appreciated.